# Extjs store.load does not make the call

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have the code ExtJs 4 :

```
var proxy = Ext.create('Ext.data.Proxy',  {
type : 'ajax',
    url : 'some url',
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    }
});
myStore.setProxy(proxy);  
myStore.load({   // this never loads, no error in console either
    scope : this,
    params : {
    },
    callback: function() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to define a `type` while creating a concrete instance of the superclass. `type` is a valid configuration when you are defining a proxy within a configuration of a class like a `Ext.data.Model` (which is the recommend way in most situations!) Following is a example how it should be done:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
});

//The Store contains the AjaxProxy as an inline configuration
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json'
    }
});

store.load();
```

The Store will now instantiate the proxy by using the applied `type` property, in this case ajax. The proxy line above is the same as

```
new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
    url: 'users.json',
    model: 'User',
    reader: 'json'
});
```

So `type` is a valid property as long as you use it in configurations of classes that consume a proxy like `Ext.data.Model` or `Ext.data.Store`

And if you ever need to create a proxy instance yourself you will need to create the concrete instance. Superclasses has documented their direct subclasses in the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy)

[image]

but in case of the reader that doesn't help because you only find `Server` & `Client` but they are listed in the class description section `Types of Proxy`

> **Types of Proxy**
>
> There are two main types of Proxy - Client and Server. The Client
>   proxies save their data locally and include the following subclasses:
>
> - LocalStorageProxy - saves its data to localStorage if the browser
>     supports it
> - SessionStorageProxy - saves its data to sessionStorage if
>     the browsers supports it
> - MemoryProxy - holds data in memory only, any
>     data is lost when the page is refreshed
>
> The Server proxies save their
>   data by sending requests to some remote server. These proxies include:
>
> - Ajax - sends requests to a server on the same domain
> - JsonP - uses JSON-P to send requests to a server on a different domain
> - Rest - uses RESTful HTTP methods (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) to communicate with server
> - Direct - uses Ext.direct.Manager to send requests
>
> Proxies operate on the principle that all operations performed are either Create, Read,
>   Update or Delete. These four operations are mapped to the methods
>   create, read, update and destroy respectively. Each Proxy subclass
>   implements these functions.
>
> The CRUD methods each expect an Operation object as the sole argument.
>   The Operation encapsulates information about the action the Store
>   wishes to perform, the model instances that are to be modified, etc.
>   See the Operation documentation for more details. Each CRUD method
>   also accepts a callback function to be called asynchronously on
>   completion.
>
> Proxies also support batching of Operations via a batch object,
>   invoked by the batch method.
>
> Available since: 1.1.0

Comment: store.load(); was the key to getting the data to load.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and got the same result you describe: No console errors, but no loading either. From what I see, `type` isn't a config option for Proxy in ExtJS 4.x, but you could instantiate `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` directly. This worked for me:

```
var proxy = Ext.create('Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',  {
    url : 'some url',
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    }
});
```

Comment: What you stated is not entirely correct because it is a valid property when you defining a config within a class that uses a proxy.